# Adding multiple controls into flow panel on non-ui thread in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker, flowlayoutpanel

Okay, I want to add multiple user controls into a flow panel at one time without the UI freezing, I've tried adding the controls from a Background Worker but get an error about how it cannot be added because it can't change parent control or something like that, any help would be appreciated.

```
 private void MainScreen_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SetAnchors();
      // GetFavoritesTVShows(favoritesPage);
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        GetFavoritesTVShows(favoritesPage);
    }
```

Error : in GetFavoritesTVSHows method : flowLayoutPanelSeries.Controls.Add(seriePopular); this line

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation is not valid: The' flowLayoutPanelSeries 'control was accessed from another thread other than the thread on which it was created.'

I want to do non freezing UI. My flowlayoutpanel is taking materials from database. So when it loads, UI freeze. I want to add progress bar to prevent that.

Comment: How many controls are you trying to add?  Adding a few controls to a panel shouldn't take long enough to freeze the UI for a human perceptible amount of time.

Comment: can you add the specific error to the question details?

Comment: I am downloading from web. Images, texts etc so it takes long to load

Answer (score -1):

Try this on your background thread.

```
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        {
            //Make your UI changes here
        });
```

Updating the UI is only valid from the UI thread, so you won't be able to do it directly from a Background Worker. However, you *are* able to invoke the changes to be made on the UI thread from another thread.

Comment: There's no point creating a background worker to do nothing but marshal back tot he UI thread.  At that point you're better off just not creating a BGW in the first place.

Comment: @Servy Without knowing more details from the OP, we don't really know everything that the background thread is doing. They mentioned not being able to access the UI thread as part of whatever it is doing and this is a solution to that

Comment: They specifically mentioned in the question that they created the BGW to add the controls to prevent the UI from freezing.

Comment: @Servy Read it again please. They didn't say the BGW was *specifically* for this just that something they tried to do involved accessing the UI thread from a BGW. For all e know the BGW is already doing other work and updating the UI is just part of it. If OP would clarify, that'd be great, but making big assumptions like that just doesn't help anyone.

Comment: They said that they're trying to add controls to a panel, and the UI was freezing, so the moved the code to a BGW, where it errored because it's editing the UI from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Oh, and if they actually had CPU bound, long running, non-UI work to do (and again, the question doesn't describe any such situation) then the appropriate way to update the UI with the results of said operation is to use the Completed event of the BGW, not to explicitly invoke in the BGW's do work handler.  The whole *point* of using a BGW is to allow it to handle marshaling to the UI on your behalf in the situations where it's appropriate to do so.

Comment: Exactly. They moved it to a BGW, they didn't say the BGW was made for the specific purpose of updating the UI. Again, @Servy, that's another made up 'if' that you're throwing in. We don't have details so stop making up your own details. It helps no one.

Comment: They said they were trying to update the UI, it wasn't working, so they moved their UI updates to a BGW.  So yes, they *did* say they created the BGW for the expressed purpose of updating the UI.  Now that may not be true, there may be non-UI work in there, but it's what the question says it's doing.

Comment: freezing and I can't see progress bar value from background worker

Comment: @cumhurcil That sounds like an entirely different issue. You could edit your post or make a new question